# images to display in dynamic grid fixed window size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need help on displaying images in window. I have a total of 20 images which will be in different size for different times.

I need to display all those 20 images in my browser window. It should not scroll. It should be as fix. Size of images should have to change according to width of the window.

Can any one please suggest any plugins to get this done.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're looking for a treemap plugin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping

Answer (score 0):

Despite the lack of any sample code, You can try and use a max-height for your main container of

```
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 100vw;
```

where **vh** stands for **viewport height** and **vw** stands for **viewport width** (e.g. the size of the window at that specific moment)

and then set Your image width for each and every child element to be **100%** by using

```
img {width: 100%}
```

on your image elements in your stylesheet.

> [**Here is an article on VW and VH units.**](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units)